# How to disable tool tip for +/- icons on jq grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

[image]

I'm getting undefiend tooltip when I move over the "+" icon.

Comment: can you show you jqgrid definition script?

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use?